# PiCamera + RaspberryPi: capture frames despite multiprocessing too slow?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, raspberry-pi, multiprocessing

im using the PiCamera, RaspberyPi and a RC-Car to follow a line on the ground. I need always the current frame from the camera as soon as possible because the RC-Car is driving pretty fast.
Therefore im using multiprocessing. I have 3 Processes.

1. Process: To get the current frame as soon as possible
2. Process: To process the current frame
3. Main Process: Right now not used.

This is my code so far.

Main.py:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event
import VideoStream
import FrameProcessor


if __name__ == "__main__":
    queue = Queue()
    event = Event()

    process_stream = Process(target = VideoStream.stream, args = (queue, event))
    process_frame = Process(target = FrameProcessor.processFrame, args = (queue, event))

    process_stream.start()
    process_frame.start()

    process_stream.join()
    process_frame.join()
```

VideoStream.py (Producer):

```
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import time


def stream(queue, event):
    camera = PiCamera()
    camera.resolution = 'VGA' #(640x480)
    camera.exposure_mode = 'sports'
    camera.start_preview()
    rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(640,480))
    time.sleep(2)

    for frame in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
        if event.is_set():
            queue.put(frame.array)
        rawCapture.truncate(0)
```

FrameProcessor.py (Consumer):

```
import cv2
import time

def processFrame(queue, event):
    time.sleep(5)

    while True:
        start = time.time()
        event.set()
        frame = queue.get()
        event.clear()
        print("frame {}: {}".format(i,time.time() - start))
        #Do herer some imageprocessing stuff
```

Output:

```
frame 0: 0.059038400650024414
frame 1: 0.035747528076171875
frame 2: 0.09440946578979492
frame 3: 0.03632092475891113
frame 4: 0.09602904319763184
frame 5: 0.03551483154296875
frame 6: 0.09793353080749512
frame 7: 0.0363461971282959
frame 8: 0.09468984603881836
frame 9: 0.03627347946166992
frame 10: 0.09724879264831543
frame 11: 0.034917354583740234
frame 12: 0.09811806678771973
frame 13: 0.03505754470825195
frame 14: 0.09569430351257324
...
...
...
```

My questions:

1.)
As you can see the output is very unusual.

```
0.3s, 0.9s, 0.3s, 0.9s, 0.3s etc. ...
```

I think there is something wrong in my code. 
That can not be a coincidence or? I always see the 0.9 and 0.3 in my outputs.

2.) When I dont use multiprocessing the time to capture a frame takes about 0.9s. So multiprocessing is not faster. Why is this so? what am I doing wrong? Multiprocessing has to be faster or?

3.) What am I doing wrong and how can I speed up the things to always get as fast as possible the picture from the camera.

Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Try commenting out all the code in the `capture_continuous()` loop to see how many frames a second it can grab without doing anything. If it can only grab 16 frames/s, it will average 60ms per frame, which is the average of 34 and 96ms.

Comment: I did, it can grab about 28-29 per second

Comment: Ok, so it takes 35ms to grab a frame. Now try grabbing just one frame and then time how long it takes to send the same frame with no further acquisition, say 1000 times. Then you can work out how long the `queue.put()` takes. Just discard the received frames on the other end.

Answer (score 0):

interesting code.

The queue you are using will be blocked by any access. Which means if two processes try to access it at the same time they will block (slower code) even if you avoided locks.
You should look for managed queues which use sockets

FrameProcessor.py is not doing anything. Maybe you could look at openCV for that. It's already compiled and therefore faster (tricky on a PI  to make it work but worthy)